# Macro implementation of putc() in C

Tags: c, io

I was looking for the macro implementation of putc() function in C.

One implementation which i found in "The C programming language" by Ritchie and Kernighan

```
#define putc(x,p) (--(p)->cnt >=0 \
                  ?(unsigned char) *(p)->ptr++ :_flushbuf((x),p))
```

The file structure definition is as follows

```
typedef struct _iobuf {
                int cnt;
                char *ptr;
                char *base;
                int flag;
                int fd;
             }FILE;
```

I am unable to see how cnt gets initialised when we call putc ?

Answer (score 5):

It's undoubtedly initialized by `fopen`, and modified by anything else that reads/writes the file.

Comment: It's initialized in the initializer for the `FILE` object `stdout` points to (which has static storage duration).

Comment: If you want to get technical, `stdout` will probably be initialized by something similar to `fdopen`, which starts from a fd instead of a file name. In any case, however, the startup code will call that to fill in an _iobuf for fd 1.

Answer (score 0):

it has initialized in the code:from K&R

```
//the stdin stdout,stderr are reserved in first 3 location of_iob[]:
FILE _iob[OPEN_MAX]={
                        {0,(char*)0,(char*)0,_READ,0},  //stdin read with buffered
                        {0,(char*)0,(char*)0,_WRITE,1}, //stdout write with buffered
                        {0,(char*)0,(char*)0,_WRITE|_UNBUF,2}, //stderr write without buffered
                };
```