# putc implemented as Macro ic C++?

Tags: c++, macros

I know [Macro implementation of putc() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713944/macro-implementation-of-putc-in-c), but is it same in C++?

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on your implementation of `cstdio`. In most cases this is really just a wrapper around `stdio.h`, with wrappers declared inside the `std` namespace, and the `C` and `C++` compilers share the same standard library for `C` functions. For example, VS2010 uses `stdio.h` for `C++`, in which `putc` is implemented as both a macro *and* a function, depending on environment and other compile-time definitions.

Comment: @FengGang You're welcome. Were you able to view your `cstdio` file and find out which one it uses? Alternatively, you could view the pre-processor output of a trivial example to see what it uses.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of C++?  C++83 (1983)?  C++98 (1998)?  C++11 (2011)?

The C++98 and C++11 Specifications rely on the ISO C specifications for C Library functions, and do not put additional implementation constraints on them, other than trivial ones like renaming stdio.h to cstdio.h and allowing inclusion without the dot-h suffix.

[See: C++98 Specification](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf)

[See: C++11 Specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Look in cstdio.h if you are interested in your particular compiler.

However, if we dig deeper and take a look at the ISO C standard: "ISO/IEC 9899:1990" (C89/C90), well, we find that it is unavailable for free viewing on the web (not even the final draft standard), so moving on to C99 (NOT ISO C), you find...

...that C99 (Not "ISO C") says putc() MAY be implemented as a macro,

[See: C99 Specification](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

So if you are really developing in Obj-C++ (which uses C99), then C99 is the relevant specification to consider, *not* ISO C (C90).  Also, since C99 lets the compiler writer decide whether to make putc() a macro or not, you should consider it an open possibility, and decide whether you really care to know about the C90 (ISO C) spec which is becoming obsolete (now that even C11 (2011) is out.)

Comment: Whatever modern, up-to-date compiler you are probably using, the odds are putc() can be implemented either way, or both, as another poster noted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.  Both C and C++ use `<stdio.h>` which has the same scheme in all implementations that I know of.

Comment: In C++ it would be `<cstdio>` and it should both be present at the global and `std` namespace, so I guess it shouldn't be a macro or at least not just a macro

Comment: @K-ballo:  That's right.  Many implementations provide both a macro and a function so that a function pointer may be manipulated.

Comment: @K-ballo:  probably correct.  Alas, I have had to work with many non-conforming implementations, especially on microcontrollers.