# Why can't putc() be implemented as a macro in C++? (Or can it?)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdio

Reading [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fputc) on fputc()/putc(), I stumbled upon the following statement:

> In C, putc() may be implemented as a macro, which is disallowed in C++.

Is this true? If so, where (in the C++ standard) is this stated?

Possibly related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712423](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712423/putc-implemented-as-macro-ic-c)

Comment: Maybe that's because http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdio.syn#header:%3ccstdio%3e doesn't list it as a macro, but I'm not sure if that's enough.

Comment: @M.A The C++ standard specifically disallows this (in general, not just for `putc`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`putc` is specified as a function in the C standard:

> 7.19.7.8 The putc function

The C standard permits any C standard library function to be implemented as a macro (a real function implementation still needs to be provided, but if a macro is defined in the header, that's what will be used):

> 7.1.4 Use of library functions
>
> Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro

But the C++ standard specifically states that these must be defined as functions:

> 17.4.1.2.6 Headers
>
> Names that are defined as functions in C shall be defined as functions in the C++ Standard Library.

The footnote explicitly clarifies that an additional macro definition is not allowed:

> This disallows the practice, allowed in C, of providing a "masking macro" in addition to the function prototype. The only way to achieve equivalent "inline" behavior in C++ is to provide a definition as an extern inlin